# Unable to Update ListBox Right way from backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress

Tags: c#, listbox, backgroundworker

Trying to update a listbox from `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged`, and it does but when `backgroundWorker1_DoWork`  completes its process. I want to update listbox before `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` is still executing and while periodically it will call `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress` and update listboxes.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // loops
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, list);// sending list to listbox
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic a = e.UserState;
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
              { listbox1.Items.Add(a[0]); });
    // updates after backgroundWorker1_DoWork is executed?
}
```

Comment: I set up an example and your code seems fine other than result[0] should be a[0]. Assuming that was a typo. It would be helpful to see what kind of looping you are doing in the DoWork method.

Comment: Sorry,Yes it is a[0]. But when I run it I see all listboxes values updated once rather than one by one? Also added listbox1.Refresh();

Comment: ProgressChanged happens on the UI thread, so you don't have to BeginInvoke anything there.  It's unclear what your variable `list` is, but if it's a single item, that's the object that would be in `e.UserState`, and that's the object you would add to the ListBox Items collection.

Comment: Are you starting your BackgroundWorker like this backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); ?

Comment: @ Hi Lars:It throws me a cross threaded operation error if I don't use invoke method.@My list is pretty long and hence a[] above.

Comment: Yes, I am starting backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(). But why? That's the way I need to call Do_work right?

Comment: It has to be *inside* `// loops`.  Not at the end of it when all the work was done.

Comment: @Hans: backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, list); is inside the loop. so that it should keep updating continueously.

Comment: There is something wrong with your code if you are getting a cross-threaded exception error in a ProgressChanged event.  Your posted code isn't showing us that code.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Please add delay

```
private void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) {
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, e.Data);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
  }
}
```

Comment: OnDataReceived?  There was no hint in your post you were doing anything like this.  It's not exactly how ReportProgress was meant to be used.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't had a clue OnDataReceived was the culprit. Anyways, thanks for help guys!

Comment: Why 300 milliseconds? http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx